# cv2.VideoCapture.read() gets old frame after time.sleep()

Tags: python, opencv

I tried to capture (stereo) images with Python's `opencv` and two cameras so therefore every 5 seconds an image should be saved. But the problem here is that an old frame is saved.

The minified code is as follows:

```
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

    for i in range(20):
        time.sleep(5)
        print "Taking image %d:" % i
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        cv2.imwrite("image %d" % i, frame)
        print "  image done." if ret else "  Error while taking image..."
    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

To check this, I changed the position of the camera after each taken image. But nevertheless an image from an old position is saved (actually not the same, but I assume some frames after the last saved image). After 5 (or more) images finally the captured location in the image does also change.

So, is there any problem with `time.sleep`? I guess that I'm not getting the actual frame, but a buffered one. If this is the case, how could I fix it and capture the actual frame?

Comment: maybe you can call `.grab` multiple times and only call `.retrieve` once for the last grabbed frame (grab followed by retrieve is the same as `.read`). But I have no idea how/whether you know that you've grabbed the last frame already...

Comment: Adding `ret, frame = cap.read()` twice worked for me, worth a try.

Comment: does sleep put the whole event loop on hold and therefore you aren't actually getting any new images?

Comment: So adding `ret, frame = cap.read()` doesn't not work for me.However I don't know how to check wheter I have the latest frame or not. Good question GPPk.

Answer (score 9):

VideoCapture is buffering.
If you always want the actual frame, do this:

```
while True:
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    cap.release()
    cv2.imshow(" ", frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(2000) != -1:
        break
```

Answer (score 4):

you need to count the elapsed time, but not stop read frames. like this:

```
import cv2
import time

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
preframe_tm = time.time()
i = 0
while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    elapsed_time = time.time() - preframe_tm
    if elapsed_time < 5:
        continue
    preframe_tm = time.time()
    i += 1
    print("Taking image %d:" % i)
    cv2.imwrite("image_%d.jpg" % i, frame)
    if i >= 20:
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```