# Call a webcam from C++ and show images in Python

Tags: python, c++

I want to call a function from C++ in Python.

In my case, I already have a lot of code in Python but I want to change the camera that I use. Some libraries for cameras only support C++.

I have successfully call C++ .dll and displaying images in Python with my code as follow. However, when Python show images very slow.

I think it becomes slow because I need to call VideoCapture in a loop.
If I only enter VideoCapture 1 time (before main function), the image only send 1 time also in Python.

This is my code for C++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2\highgui\highgui.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

Mat img;
Mat frameRGB;
vector<Mat>ch;
Mat1f datas, datas2, datas3, datas4;
float tmp_buf[640 * 480 * 3];
int tmp_buf_sz = 0;

VideoCapture cap;

#define LIBDLL extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)

LIBDLL int returnQ(float *data_img, int x)
{
    if(x==1)
    {
        cap.open(0);
        cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 640);
        cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 480);
        cap.set(CAP_PROP_FPS, 30);
    }

    cap >> frameRGB;
    img = frameRGB.clone();

    split(img, ch);
    ch[0].convertTo(datas, CV_32F);
    datas = datas.reshape(1, 1).t();
    ch[1].convertTo(datas2, CV_32F);
    datas2 = datas2.reshape(1, 1).t();
    ch[2].convertTo(datas3, CV_32F);
    datas3 = datas3.reshape(1, 1).t();

    vconcat(datas, datas2, datas4);
    vconcat(datas4, datas3, datas4);

    tmp_buf_sz = 640 * 480 * 3;
    memcpy(data_img, datas4.data, sizeof(float)*tmp_buf_sz);

    waitKey(1);

    return *data_img;
}
```

And my code for Python:

```
import cv2
import ctypes
from ctypes import * 
import numpy as np

dll = cdll.LoadLibrary(r"./UVCStreamerTest.dll")
dll.returnQ.restype = c_int
data_img = (c_float * 921600)()

x=1

while(True):

    ss = dll.returnQ(data_img, x)
    if ss!=0:   

       x=0

       im = np.array(data_img)
       im = np.uint8(im)

       # Convert to BGR

        B = im[0:640*480]
        G = im[(640*480):(640*480*2)]
        R = im[(640*480*2):]

        B = B.reshape(480, 640)
        G = G.reshape(480, 640)
        R = R.reshape(480, 640)

        img = cv2.merge((B,G,R))    

        cv2.imshow("Image",img)
        cv2.waitKey(1)
```

Is there a way for better communication between C++ and Python?

When C++ has the task of activating the camera and sending images to Python.

This webcam call from C++ is just an example for the communication between C++ and Python. If it successful, I will change my camera which use specific library for UVC camera in C++.
The flowchart will be the same, C++ capture image from camera and send to Python, then Python show the images.

Thank you in advance.

Edit:
I found the solution. 
Only need to add: cap.open(0)

I edit my code above in case someone has the same problem.

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/unclearquestion It's unclear which problem you want to help with; for half of your description, there's no info to diagnose it; you may be [solving a wrong problem in the first place](http://xyproblem.info/). It's also off topic to ask about multiple things at once

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev which part is not clear? why you give me -1?

Comment: For me the part with question is unclear. The only question I can find is _"Does anyone have a better suggestion?"_.

Comment: @ThomasSablik OK, I already edit my question. Please don't be so rude, this is my first time to ask here. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: You are doing things in a wrong way AFAICS so unless you have a very good reason you expect it to work properly, I cannot help you because it's not supposed to work properly.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev If I call a video from file it already successful. I put VideoCapture once before main function and call frame in a loop. But, when I try to use webcam that's my problem: if I put VideoCapture once and call frame in a loop, python can't get images continuous. You can try just put loop in my c++ and put VideoCapture before function to call a video file, it's already successful.

Comment: You are waiting for a keypress after every frame. How are you expecting to get them "continuously"?

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev waitKey(1) is not waiting a key to press, it just to give some delay. I already try to delete it, the problem still the same. Python can't get frame continuous if I didn't call VideoCapture every time before send the image.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cv2.VideoCapture.read() gets old frame after time.sleep()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34656304/cv2-videocapture-read-gets-old-frame-after-time-sleep)

Comment: If the duplicate doesn't fit, upgrade your code to a [mcve] -- which includes actual and expected behavior, "can't get" is not a problem description.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev actually, this webcam call from c++ is only example. If it successful I will change it to my camera library which use specific library for UVC camera and not use opencv. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: An "example" that is not a [mcve] is useless, see http://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/. E.g. your c++ code has undeclared variables.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev OK, I edit my code and put the variable part.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Boost.Python](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/python/doc/html/index.html)

I think it is more convient than the "cdll.LoadLibrary()"